# Is getline in awk command safe to use?

Tags: awk

I got weird comments on posting an `awk` answer on SO which uses the `getline` function.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24448817/3297613) is the link to that answer.

After posting my answer, a user came up with the below comment,(<sub>I don't criticize him.</sub>)

> Not a good solution, it will join lines regardless of content and not process more lines if needed. And you should avoid using getline.

It states that we should avoid the `getline` function in `awk`. So my questions are,

- Is it safe to use `getline` function in awk?
- In what circumstances should we use `getline` in what cases shouldn't we?
- If this function produces unexpected results then why don't we file a bug report?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with awk's `getline` function per se. It can be a code smell though as it is easily misused, either (a) in un-idiomatic constructions when awk already supports line-by-line *pattern-action* operation, or (b) in attempting tasks too complicated for awk. I would liken it to the much debated `goto` statement in C in these respects: potentially useful, easily abused.

Comment: I mostly use getline in the BEGIN to get information and fill arrays that I will later use when processing the main file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most people argue over `getline` on *coding style* ground.

It's alien to the normal `awk` processing of have the code process one record at a time.

`getline` (when not used as `getline var < "file"` or `"cmd" | getline`) pulls in the next record (possibly from the next file) in the middle of the code statement. It's easy to lose track of the fact that it increments NR, FNR, may change FILENAME.

Another thing not to forget about when using it is to check its return value, as it will return 0 on EOF or <0 on error.

So it's not `getline` or `if/while (getline) ...`, it's:

```
if/while ((getline) > 0) { .... }
```

Or:

```
if/while ((getline < "file") > 0) {...}
```

Most of the usages of `getline` can be turned round by using a state-machine like approach.

Instead of:

```
/pattern/ {getline; print}
```

Which is probably wrong and should be written:

```
/pattern/ && (getline) > 0 {print}
```

You would do:

```
found_pattern {print; found_pattern=0}
/pattern/{found_pattern=1}
```

Also note how the two are different if *pattern* is matched on two consecutive lines.

Now, as long as you're aware of that, `getline` is fine. If you do want to process several files at the same time, then you do need `getline`, but remember to check the return value:

```
while ((getline a < "a") > 0 && (getline b < "b") > 0) {
  ....
```