# Applying function to first column and inserting it as second

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, columns

So I have been searching like crazy, but I still have not found a satisfactory solution. I have some output which looks like the following

```
kdeconnec   1625     1000   11u  IPv6 414426      0t0  UDP *:1716 
vivaldi-b   1937     1000  263u  IPv4 440390      0t0  UDP 224.0.0.251:5353 
electron    9522     1000   23u  IPv4 414465      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.17:58692->157.240.194.18:443 (ESTABLISHED)
flask      27084     1000    3u  IPv4 109532      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3000 (LISTEN)
firefox    27094     1000   99u  IPv4 425877      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.17:34114->54.191.222.112:443 (ESTABLISHED)
python     36425     1000    3u  IPv4 109532      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3000 (LISTEN)
chromium  110937     1000  130u  IPv4 439461      0t0  UDP 224.0.0.251:5353
```

I want to apply a function called `exec_path_from_process_id` to each value in the *second* column, and insert it as the *second* column. Resulting in the following. The exact formating (alignment) is not important, as long as it is aligned.

```
kdeconnec  /usr/lib/kdeconnectd        1625    1000  11u   IPv6  414426  0t0  UDP  *:1716                                  
vivaldi-b  /opt/vivaldi/vivaldi-bin    1937    1000  263u  IPv4  440390  0t0  UDP  224.0.0.251:5353                        
electron   /usr/lib/electron/electron  9522    1000  23u   IPv4  414465  0t0  TCP  192.168.0.17:58692->157.240.194.18:443  (ESTABLISHED)
flask      /usr/bin/python3.10         27084   1000  3u    IPv4  109532  0t0  TCP  127.0.0.1:3000                          (LISTEN)
firefox    /usr/lib/firefox/firefox    27094   1000  99u   IPv4  425877  0t0  TCP  192.168.0.17:34114->54.191.222.112:443  (ESTABLISHED)
python     /usr/bin/python3.10         36425   1000  3u    IPv4  109532  0t0  TCP  127.0.0.1:3000                          (LISTEN)
chromium   /usr/lib/chromium/chromium  110937  1000  130u  IPv4  439461  0t0  UDP  224.0.0.251:5353                        
kioslave5  /usr/lib/kf5/kioslave5      133514  1000  6u    IPv4  499063  0t0  TCP  192.168.0.17:54238->84.208.4.225:443    (ESTABLISHED)
```

My current code is a hot mess, but I got it working at least. The only restraint is that it has to work on bash 3.2+

```
listeners=$(
    lsof -Pnl +M -i |
        awk -F" " '!_[$1]++' |
        tail -n +2
)

function exec_path_from_process_id () {
    local pid="${1}"
    path=$(readlink -f /proc/"$pid"/exe)
    if [ -z "${path}" ]; then
        path=$(awk '{print $(NF)}' <<< $(ls -alF /proc/"$pid"/exe))
    fi
    echo ${path:-null}
}

pids=($(awk '{ print $2 }' <<< "$listeners"))
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a listeners_array <<< "$listeners"
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a paths <<< $(for i in "${pids[@]}"; do exec_path_from_process_id "$i"; done)
for i in "${!pids[@]}"; do
  row="${listeners_array[i]}"
  row=$(awk -v r="${paths[i]}" '{ print $1 " " r " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7 " " $8 " " $9 " " $10}' <<< $row)
  printf '%s\n' "${row[@]}"
done | column -t
```

Comment: @ibuprofen For instance I get it for flatpak and sometimes snap packages

Comment: Ah, OK. Could use `realpath -m` instead perhaps

Comment: YMMV with piping the output to `column -t` to get alignment since that will split the input at any field that contains blanks, e.g. a file path. You can see in your question it's already splitting the final field on each line into 2 separate fields, e.g. `<127.0.0.1:3000  (LISTEN)>` becomes `<127.0.0.1:3000> <(LISTEN)>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```c
lsof -Pnl +M -i | awk '
# Use: NR > 1 to skip header
NR > 1 && !x[$1]++ {
    # realpath -m
    # (no path components need exist or be a directory)
    cmd = "realpath -m /proc/"$2"/exe"
    cmd | getline path
    close(cmd)
    # We can edit field $2 and print $0
    $2 = path" "$2
    print $0
}' | column -t
```

The line `cmd | getline path` executes the command `cmd` and reads the output into variable `path`. The command is not closed unless one do `close(expression)`, hence I have it in a variable.

Comment: This looks really promissing! what does the line `c | getline p` do?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar expanded on it a little. See also for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960895/3342816 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139559/140633 etc.

Comment: If there are any spaces in `exe` paths the result will be mangled though.

Comment: `cmd = "realpath -m /proc/"$2"/exe"` should be `cmd = "realpath -m \047/proc/"$2"/exe\047"` or the contents of `$2` will be exposed to the shell for globbing, word splitting, and filename expansion. `cmd | getline path` should be `if ( (cmd | getline path) > 0 ) { ...` or similar to protect against failures in `cmd | getline`, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: Regarding `!x[$1]++` = an array used in that context is commonly, idiomatically named `seen` instead of `x` for clarity, i.e. `!seen[$1]++`. Changing a field as in `$2 = path" "$2` will change all of the white space on the line to individual blank chars which may be undesirable. I know the OP is outputing to `column -t` but that will corrupt the output if a `path` contains spaces. `print $0` can be written as just `print` since `$0` is what is printed by default.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 3):

You said you don't care about formatting as long as the fields are aligned so, just pick a width that'll be wide enough for your needs and then:

```
$ while read -r a pid b; do
    printf "%-12s%-10s%10s %s\n" "$a" "<$(wc -c <<<"$pid")>" "$pid" "$b"
done < <(lsof -Pnl +M -i)
kdeconnec   <5>             1625 1000   11u  IPv6 414426      0t0  UDP *:1716
vivaldi-b   <5>             1937 1000  263u  IPv4 440390      0t0  UDP 224.0.0.251:5353
electron    <5>             9522 1000   23u  IPv4 414465      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.17:58692->157.240.194.18:443 (ESTABLISHED)
flask       <6>            27084 1000    3u  IPv4 109532      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3000 (LISTEN)
firefox     <6>            27094 1000   99u  IPv4 425877      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.17:34114->54.191.222.112:443 (ESTABLISHED)
python      <6>            36425 1000    3u  IPv4 109532      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3000 (LISTEN)
chromium    <7>           110937 1000  130u  IPv4 439461      0t0  UDP 224.0.0.251:5353
```

The above assumes your first column doesn't contain any spaces.

Obviously just change `<$(wc -c <<<"$pid")>` to whatever the real command is you need to run and the first `%-10s` to be whatever max width string that command could output. If you REALLY feel there is no max value you could use for that width, let us know as then it'd take a 2-pass approach - 1 to produce the output and then 2 to format the output. If you're happy with using `column -t` for the formatting then it'd be (replace `file` with `<(lsof -Pnl +M -i)` which obviously I don't really have available):

```
$ while read -r a pid b; do
    printf "%s %s %s %s\n" "$a" "<$(wc -c <<<"$pid")>" "$pid" "$b"
done < file | column -t
kdeconnec  <5>  1625    1000  11u   IPv6  414426  0t0  UDP  *:1716
vivaldi-b  <5>  1937    1000  263u  IPv4  440390  0t0  UDP  224.0.0.251:5353
electron   <5>  9522    1000  23u   IPv4  414465  0t0  TCP  192.168.0.17:58692->157.240.194.18:443  (ESTABLISHED)
flask      <6>  27084   1000  3u    IPv4  109532  0t0  TCP  127.0.0.1:3000                          (LISTEN)
firefox    <6>  27094   1000  99u   IPv4  425877  0t0  TCP  192.168.0.17:34114->54.191.222.112:443  (ESTABLISHED)
python     <6>  36425   1000  3u    IPv4  109532  0t0  TCP  127.0.0.1:3000                          (LISTEN)
chromium   <7>  110937  1000  130u  IPv4  439461  0t0  UDP  224.0.0.251:5353
```

but that would fail if any part of your line contained spaces, e.g. the output of the command you're running on the pid.

Since you asked, here's a 2-pass approach:

1. Instead of outputting text that has spaces separating fields and newlines separating records as above, produce output that uses newlines to separate fields and NUL to separate records:

```
while read -r a pid b; do printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\0" "$a" "<$(wc -c <<<"$pid")>" "$pid" "$b"; done < file
```

2. Write an awk script that reads NUL-separated records containing newline-separated fields, calculate the max width of each field when reading the input and output each field in that width when printing the output, recombining the fields into single lines:

```
$ while read -r a pid b; do printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\0" "$a" "<$(wc -c <<<"$pid")>" "$pid" "$b"; done < file |
awk -v RS='\0' -F'\n' '
    { recs[NR]=$0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) wids[i]=(length($i)>wids[i] ? length($i) : wids[i]) }
    END { for (n=1; n<=NR; n++) { $0=recs[n]; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%-*s%s", wids[i], $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS) } }
'
kdeconnec <5> 1625   1000   11u  IPv6 414426      0t0  UDP *:1716
vivaldi-b <5> 1937   1000  263u  IPv4 440390      0t0  UDP 224.0.0.251:5353
electron  <5> 9522   1000   23u  IPv4 414465      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.17:58692->157.240.194.18:443 (ESTABLISHED)
flask     <6> 27084  1000    3u  IPv4 109532      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3000 (LISTEN)
firefox   <6> 27094  1000   99u  IPv4 425877      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.17:34114->54.191.222.112:443 (ESTABLISHED)
python    <6> 36425  1000    3u  IPv4 109532      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3000 (LISTEN)
chromium  <7> 110937 1000  130u  IPv4 439461      0t0  UDP 224.0.0.251:5353
```

That requires an awk that can read NUL-separated input, e.g. GNU awk. It assumes that none of your path names or other fields can contain newlines.

If you REALLY wanted to do all of the above in a single awk script, that means awk would have to spin off a subshell every time your external command is called which would be slow and you'd have to ensure you get the quoting right (see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) but here you go, assuming no spaces that you care about retaining within fields in your input but non-newline spaces in paths would be fine:

```
$ awk '
    {
        recs[NR] = $0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            lgth = length($i)
            wids[i] = ( lgth > wids[i] ? lgth : wids[i] )
        }

        cmd = "wc -c <<<\047" $2 "\047"
        paths[NR] = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "N/A" )
        close(cmd)
        lgth = length(paths[NR])
        pathWid = ( lgth > pathWid ? lgth : pathWid )

    }
    END {
        for (n=1; n<=NR; n++) {
            $0 = recs[n]
            for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                if ( i == 2 ) {
                    printf "%-*s%s", pathWid, paths[n], OFS
                }
                printf "%-*s%s", wids[i], $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
    }
' < file
kdeconnec 5 1625   1000 11u  IPv6 414426 0t0 UDP *:1716
vivaldi-b 5 1937   1000 263u IPv4 440390 0t0 UDP 224.0.0.251:5353
electron  5 9522   1000 23u  IPv4 414465 0t0 TCP 192.168.0.17:58692->157.240.194.18:443 (ESTABLISHED)
flask     6 27084  1000 3u   IPv4 109532 0t0 TCP 127.0.0.1:3000                         (LISTEN)
firefox   6 27094  1000 99u  IPv4 425877 0t0 TCP 192.168.0.17:34114->54.191.222.112:443 (ESTABLISHED)
python    6 36425  1000 3u   IPv4 109532 0t0 TCP 127.0.0.1:3000                         (LISTEN)
chromium  7 110937 1000 130u IPv4 439461 0t0 UDP 224.0.0.251:5353
```

Comment: Hmm, would normal file paths ever contain spaces? I do not min the end of the output getting aligned.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar yes, file paths often contain spaces, assuming they won't and so not handling them properly when they do is a common point of failure for shell scripts.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I would be interested in the two pass solution then. As the number of elements is quite small the difference in speed would be negligible.

Comment: OK I posted a 2-pass approach. I'm using a shell loop to run your shell command (which is what shell is good for), then an awk script to format the output (which is what awk is good for).